# how to get data from elastic search by using id which contains "/"

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I am using the old version of elastic search 1.7.3 , and this is my structure of index

```
        "_index": "&kashyap",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "avatar:image/c7aa819e-f323-5728-9c80-0826937145b",
```

this is my source data:

```
_source": {
               "~id": "c7aa819e-f323-5728-9c80-0826937145b",
               "username":"suhas"

                 }
```

how to get a particular document by id or update a particular by id?

tried in following manner  with index, but to no avail
http://localhost:9200/&kashyap/entity/avatar:image/c7aa819e-f323-5728-9c80-0826937145b/_search

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to encoding URL bypasses a special character in _id